# Highcharts data from google spreadsheet hide all series except one at start

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, spreadsheet

I am trying to get data from google spreadsheet and then displaying it through highcharts. 
Following code does the magic.

```
$('#container4').highcharts({
    data: {
        googleSpreadsheetKey: '0AtF0efQI2GskdE5Yei1VODZuTlBKUi1rc0JnNmxRQVE'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Playground'
    }
});
```

I want to hide all series except first one on initial load. Then user can show/hide as default functionality of highcharts.

Any help?

Here is jsfiddle link. 
http://jsfiddle.net/sulmanpucit/AYYCv/141/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide all series by default using plotOptions. Then in callback show first series: http://jsfiddle.net/AYYCv/142/

```
$('#container4').highcharts({
    data: {
        googleSpreadsheetKey: '0AtF0efQI2GskdE5Yei1VODZuTlBKUi1rc0JnNmxRQVE'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            visible: false
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Playground'
    }
}, function(chart) {
    chart.series[0].show();   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to pre-process your data somehow. To do it after you have parsed the data into json and have created your series you can use the [`visible`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.visible) property like so:

```
series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    visible: false
}, {
    data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]
}]
```